# Longitude and latitude GPSTracker Android always return 0,0

Tags: android, gps

I am implementing GPS Tracker for getting Longitude and latitude from http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/.

To get value Longitude and latitude, i use this code:

```
    gps = new GPSTracker(context);

    latitude_user= gps.getLatitude();
    longitude_user  = gps.getLongitude();
```

**Some device always return 0,0 value, for some devices it works well**...
so how to fix it ?

this is the GPS Tracker.class

```
package com.tracking.bus.maps;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        getLatitude();
        getLongitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

and I have already put below permission

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: how are you getting this to work? You extend Service, but you have no default constructor. From what you posted, this should only run once when you instantiate, no?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not updating received location in onLocationChanged(), try this:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
    getLatitude();
    getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: i m using same code but the issue is i m not recieving location inside my room even gps is enabled and i have put condition to find locatio n either by network provider or gps provider but still when i went outside my room then i got location ? how can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: It happens just because your phone can't get gps signal inside a room. You will always need to go outside to catch it. Or you can emulate gps via an emulator (android avd or genymotion, for example). Last one is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

use play service

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

updated way to getting lat long in android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context context;
    private MarshMallowPermission permission;
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 60000;
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);

        context = this;

        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        permission = new MarshMallowPermission(context);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();

        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (permission.checkPermissionForLocation()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permissions Grant");
                    checkLocationSettings();
                } else {
                    permission.requestPermissionForLocation();
                }
            } else {
                checkLocationSettings();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }

    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest,
                    this
            ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "LocationChanged");
        if (location != null) {
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            Log.d(TAG, "Latitude:  " + location.getLatitude() + "\n" + "Longitude:  " + location.getLongitude());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }




    @Override
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                        "upgrade location settings ");
                try {
                    status.startResolutionForResult(FindPartyActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                }
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                        "not created.");
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "requestCode---" + requestCode + "     " + "grantResults----" + grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MarshMallowPermission.LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Permissions Grant");
                    checkLocationSettings();
                } else {
                    //Permissions Deny
                }
        }
    }
}
```